# How to store programmatically created files on Galaxy Nexus?

Tags: android, storage, android-sdcard, galaxy-nexus

I want to create an application to capture videos and store the captured videos on the sdcard. But Nexus does not have an sdcard so the application gives me an exception and says:

> Unfortunately the application has closed.

I tried saving the captured videos on the internal memory but cannot access the videos. Also the videos are not listed in the device gallery.

Where should an application store the data on a Nexus device?

Comment: You need to post some code because the Nexus does have an internal sdcard memory.  You should be using the system call to get the path to that area for saving files.

Answer (score 2):

Galaxy Nexus does have a mount to the sdcard using

```
/mnt/shell/emulated/0
```

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14859132/560435) for gory details on the mounts...

You could also store your app files in the folder returned by

```
ContextWrapper.getFilesDir()
```

that path will be something like:-

```
/data/data/$YOUR.PACKAGE/files
```

Answer (score 2):

use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()` to get a path to the external storage on any given device. You should be using this instead of hardcoding `/sdcard/`

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() will give the path "/mnt/sdcard"  But there is no sdcard on the